# How do I disable special handling of & on Qt button labels?

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts, acceleratorkey

I have inherited a virtual keyboard system with an array of buttons, one for each key.  The label for each button is a single `QChar`.  When showing the "symbols" keyboard, the code uses an '&' `QChar` for a key label, but the key shows as blank.  I'm sure Qt is processing the '&' as a shortcut key prefix. Similarly, the entered text is shown on another, longer, button label; this label, as well, handles '&' character as an accelerator.  Entering "ABC&DEF" is shown as "ABCDEF" with the 'D' underlined.

I have tried building with `QT_NO_SHORTCUT` #defined, but that made no difference.

Does anyone know of an easy way to disable this special handling of '&'?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is found in Qt doc. [`QAbstractButton::text`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#text-prop):

> If the text contains an ampersand character ('&'), a shortcut is automatically created for it. The character that follows the '&' will be used as the shortcut key. Any previous shortcut will be overwritten or cleared if no shortcut is defined by the text. See the QShortcut documentation for details. **To display an actual ampersand, use '&&'**.

(Emphasize by me.)

`QPushButton` is derived from `QAbstractButton` inheriting this behavior.

Sample `testQPushButtonAmp.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPushButton qBtn("Text with &&");
  qBtn.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQPushButtonAmp.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQPushButtonAmp.cc

QT = widgets
```

Compiled and tested on [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQPushButtonAmp.pro

$ make

$ ./testQPushButtonAmp
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

[image: snapshot of testQPushButtonAmp]

---

Concerning *how to disable this default behavior*:

I had a look at woboq.org [`QAbstractButton::setText()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractbutton.cpp.html#_ZN15QAbstractButton7setTextERK7QString).

```
void QAbstractButton::setText(const QString &text)
{
    Q_D(QAbstractButton);
    if (d->text == text)
        return;
    d->text = text;
#ifndef QT_NO_SHORTCUT
    QKeySequence newMnemonic = QKeySequence::mnemonic(text);
    setShortcut(newMnemonic);
#endif
    d->sizeHint = QSize();
    update();
    updateGeometry();
#ifndef QT_NO_ACCESSIBILITY
    QAccessibleEvent event(this, QAccessible::NameChanged);
    QAccessible::updateAccessibility(&event);
#endif
}
```

So, `QT_NO_SHORTCUT` disables to retrieve the shortcut out of text **but** it has to be defined when Qt library is built from source. Actually, I'm afraid even with disabled shortcuts, the single `&` will still become invisible in output.

I digged deeper in `woboq.org` and found some promising candidates e.g.:

[`qt_set_sequence_auto_menmonic()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic)

> Specifies whether mnemonics for menu items, labels, etc., should be honored or not. On Windows and X11, this feature is on by default; on [macOS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html#macos), it is off. When this feature is off (that is, when b is false), [QKeySequence::mnemonic()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#mnemonic) always returns an empty string.
>
> **Note:** This function is not declared in any of Qt's header files. To use it in your application, declare the function prototype before calling it.

and a sample in [`QProxyStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html#details)

```
#include "textedit.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProxyStyle>

class MyProxyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
  public:
    int styleHint(StyleHint hint, const QStyleOption *option = 0,
                  const QWidget *widget = 0, QStyleHintReturn *returnData = 0) const override
    {
        if (hint == QStyle::SH_UnderlineShortcut)
            return 0;
        return QProxyStyle::styleHint(hint, option, widget, returnData);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(textedit);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setStyle(new MyProxyStyle);
    TextEdit mw;
    mw.resize(700, 800);
    mw.show();
    //...
}
```

which I tried in my sample.

Finally, nothing of them achieved the desired effect, i.e. only `"&&"` was rendered as `&` but `"&"` never.

__

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  What I really want to know, though, is how to disable this default behavior.

Comment: @JohnB I digged a bit deeper but with no luck. (See my extended answer.)